# UI Router error : Unknown provider: $transitionsProvider <- $transitions

Tags: angularjs, webpack, angular-ui-router, transition

**UI Router version :** 
1.0.18
**Angular version:**
1.6.4
**Webpack version:**
4.15.1
**Webpack dev server version:**
3.1.4

Hello everyone,

I'm developing an AngularJS app and I'm using UI router to design my routes. Recently, I updated my webpack (3 -> 4) and my @uirouter (1.0.7->1.0.18) version, and from nowhere, I have the following error thrown:

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $transitionsProvider <- $transitions

Results: my hooks don't work and my login page is not displayed.

There is some important line of my app.js which is my main module:

```
import uiRouter from '@uirouter/angularjs';
...
export default angular.module(app,[uiRouter,....])
     .value('constants',constants)
    .config(config)
    .run(run)
    .run(authHook)
    .name;
```

And there is a draft of one of my hook where $transition service is used:

```
authRequiredHook.$inject = ['$transitions','$location'];
export default function authRequiredHook($transitions,$location) {

    $transitions.onStart({ to:(state) => {
            return state.includes.index;
        }},(trans) => {
        let authService = trans.injector().get('AuthenticationService');
        let localStorageService = trans.injector().get('LocalStorageService');
        if(!authService.isLoggedIn()){
            localStorageService.logout();
            localStorageService.setReferer($location.path());
            return trans.router.stateService.target('login');
        }
    });
}
```

Am I doing something wrong? I've been pulling out hairs of my head for 2 days...

Thank you!

Comment: I had a similar problem after upgrading ui-router. I was using a file that had ui-router's core and its angularjs implementations bundled. However, when I included the two files separately (`@uirouter/core/_bundles/ui-router-core.min.js`, `@uirouter/angularjs/release/ui-router-angularjs.min.js`), the problem vanished.

Comment: @jsruok not working for me unfortunately... :'(